# Ansible и Windows

Tags: windows, ansible

Существует ли поддержка Ansible в Windows powershell? Или его возможно поднять только по Cygwin? Как его установить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Windows - клиент.

Это стандартный случай использования ansible, описанный в [документации](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html). Требования:

#### На управляющей машине

1. Ansible версии 1.7+
2. Python модуль *pywinrm*: `pip install "pywinrm>=0.1.1"`
3. В соответствующем `group_vars` [установить несколько переменных для настройки соединения](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#inventory) с windows-хостами. Этот `group_vars` должен быть зашифрован с помощью ansible-vault.
4. Если необходима авторизация через kerberos: `pip install kerberos` и [дополнительная конфигурация kerberos](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#configuring-kerberos).

#### На клиенте

1. Для работы большей части модулей ansible понадобится Powershell 3.0, доступный начиная с Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP1. Есть также [скрипт для быстрой установки Powershell 3.0](https://github.com/cchurch/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/upgrade_to_ps3.ps1).

## Windows - управляющая машина

Официальная документация говорит о том, что эта возможность не поддерживается и не планируется. Но варианты решения всё-таки есть.

Очевидный способ решения: <s>вылить воду из чайника, чем свести задачу к предыдущей</s> поставить Linux в виртуальной машине и работать с него.

Jeff Geerling описывает [способ установки через cygwin](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/running-ansible-within-windows). Если кратко, требования такие:

1. Cygwin c набором необходимых модулей
2. Отдельно установить и сконфигурировать Ansible, [PyYAML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML/3.10), [Jinja2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.6)
3. При необходимости работы через прокси, дополнительно сконфигурировать `.bash_profile` вашего cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

[Тут](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html) говорится, что да. В качестве бэкенда юзает winrm. Ставить ничего не надо. Ansible - безклиентская система управления. В отличии от [puppet](https://puppet.com/).

Там же говорится, что в качестве управляющего сервера нужен всё-таки linux.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Windows 10 1809, можно запустить Ansible внутри WSL (по сути в той-же виртуальной машине, как предложил Nick Volynkin)

Набросал скрипт для этого, если кому надо - пользуйтесь
https://github.com/rikipm/ansible-on-windows-wsl